# Make JS Promise that resolves once a value is returned

Tags: javascript, react-apollo

I have a react apollo graphql query which is `{..., loading: true}`, and after about 1 second it will be `loading: false`. I want the `new Promise` to `resolve()` after `loading: false`.

Do I need to specify how often it checks? Like every 100 ms? Do I use a `while` loop? If you could write the code I would greatly appreciate it, I've already tried for hours without success.

Example:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   while (this.props.query.loading){
     //rerun function
   }
   resolve(this.props.query.data)
}).then((data)=>{
  //run my code
   this.setState({data: data});
});
```

**EDIT:
My issue is solved,** but the question isn't answered. No need to answer now though unless you think it would help someone else.

Comment: Can you share the code you currently have, even if it doesn't work right now?

Comment: @Luca Just updated

Comment: No, you shouldn't poll ("repeatedly check whether it changed") at all. You should just resolve the promise from the very code that changes it.

Comment: First, you want to change new Promise((reject, resolve).. to new Promise((resolve, reject)....

Comment: Wait, aren't props in react supposed to be immutable?

Comment: Then, there must be some callback or event or something you can hook into that is called when it finishes loading.  In that callback, call resolve().

Comment: You can write in `componentWillReceiveProps` so when ever the props will get update it will get called.

Comment: OK I will try some of these ideas/comments

Comment: I still think not enough info since I want to know how you set loading to false what actually tells your app that?

Answer (score 0):

using `componentWillReceiveProps()` solved my issue, although I am not sure how to create the promise like I mentioned in the question, it appeared that this.props.query wasn't a promise when I attempted to use `this.props.query.then(...)`, although I may have done it incorrectly.